# File transfers by USB stalling and failing

Tags: usb, android

I connect to my Samsung Galaxy S2 by USB from my Ubuntu 11.10 computer. It was working fine up until a few days ago.

Now, for reasons I can't determine, whenever I try to copy any files using the file manager (Nautilus), the transfer always stops at around 10 to 15% done, and then it hangs. The only way to kill the process is to disconnect the USB physically.

I thought maybe this was a problem with the SD card having an error, so I reformatted it, but that hasn't helped. Also, the same thing happens with the Galaxy's internal USB storage as well.

This seems to be an Ubuntu problem, as I tested transferring files on a Windows computer and it went through without any issues.

Comment: I assume you have enough free space?

Comment: Tons of free space. :)

Comment: I flagged this for moderator attention, as it seems the issue has magically gone away, probably the result of upgrades or some other change.

Answer (score 1):

Is your phone perhaps going into low power mode / screen lock?  The native Ubuntu drivers may not be keeping it awake over USB.

It works fine for me on 10.04, but I also have [ADB](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html) installed which may be making a difference.  Have you tried [installing ADB](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)?  (the Eclipse plugin is purely for devs, I don't have it installed myself)